# Can I create shortcuts for long console commands in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have quite often some very long console commands like:

```
python /var/www/closure-library/closure/bin/calcdeps.py \
-i myJSFile.js \
-p ../closure-library/closure/goog/ \
-o compiled \
-c /var/www//closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar \
-f "--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" \
-f "--define=goog.LOCALE='de'" > myOutputFile.js
```

and I would like to use simply:

```
closure -i myJSFile.js -o myOutputFile.js
```

or something simmilar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up `aliases` in your shell's manpage.

Perhaps something like:

```
alias closure='python /var/www/closure-library/closure/bin/calcdeps.py -p ../closure-library/closure/goog/ -c /var/www//closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar -f "--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" -o compiled'
```

Then you could do

```
$ closure -i myJSFile.js > myOutputFile.js
```

Comment: Note that aliases are forgotten between sessions so you'll need to write this into your `.bashrc` or another startup file.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a script too and handle `-o myOutputFile.js` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
   echo "Usage: closure InputFile OutputFile"
   exit 1
fi

python /var/www/closure-library/closure/bin/calcdeps.py \
-i "$1" \
-p ../closure-library/closure/goog/ \
-o compiled \
-c /var/www//closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar \
-f "--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" \
-f "--define=goog.LOCALE='de'" > "$2"
```

And you could do `closure myJSFile.js myOutputFile.js`